# CodeIgniter: add custom rewrite rule to redirect from static file to controller

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

Lets say that I have a static app and a JSON file that feeds it.

The problem is that the JSON file it's not available yet and I can't use it, so, to make the application run in development environment, I want to add a rewrite rule to redirect the JSON request to a CI controller path that will return a JSON as well.

My htaccess file looks like this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|assets|static|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

#Rewrite for development
RewriteRule ^static/app/json/appData.json$ /buscador/getAppData
```

The first condition is the CI main condition to redirect all request to `index.php`

Then I added the RewriteRule for the JSON file that's going to be located in `static/app/json/appData.json` and it needs to be redirected to the CI controller `buscador/getAppData`

The thing is that this Rewrite Rule isn't working and I don't know why, can somebody tell me what is wrong o how can I add a custom rewrite rule in CI?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was pondering on a similar problem for quite a few hours. I needed to add a custom RewriteRile so that a shorter link should be generated (and working) in order to be sent as a footer in an SMS to users. I finally managed to do it with a 301 redirect **before** the CI redirects. Here's my .htaccess:

```
Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

#Custom redirect
RewriteRule ^nv([0-9]+?)?$  /news/locate/item/$1    [NC,L,R=301]

#Remove trailing slash against SEO duplicates
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

#Generic controller redirects
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Now `http://domain.tld/nv1234` redirects to `http://domain.tld/news/locate/item/1234` as intended, although not as transparently as I would like it to, but I couldn't find a better way.
Please note the **R=301** in the Custom redirect line - the RewriteRule will not work if the client is not redirected to the newsController.

Posting my solution here with the hope that other developers will not get lost as I (and the OP) did.